# Insertar varios registros a la vez desde una tabla

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo esta tabla que está cargada con datos de la base de datos y lo que el usuario tiene que hacer es seleccionar el que quiere y completar los datos tanto de la selección como de la entrada, y esos datos se pueden guardar en registros separados. Es la primera vez que trabajo con esto por lo que desconozco un poco el proceso.

Actualmente mi vista lo tengo de esta manera:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($vsoftware as $cli)
    <tr>                         
        <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">
            <input type="checkbox" name="id_software[]" value="{{$cli->id_software}}">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">{{ $cli->nom_soft}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">{{ $cli->marca}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">{{ $cli->nombre_ver}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">{{ $cli->num_version}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">
            <select class="mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="id_tipo_venta[]"  >
                <option value="" selected>sale...</option>
                <option value="1">Key</option>
                <option value="2">Instal</option>
                <option value="3">Key + Instal</option>
                <option value="3">Viruz</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">                                                                                                
            <input name="obs_software[]" class=" form-control" type="text"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

mi controlador trato de formarlo así:

```
$soft_instal = new Software_instalacion;
    $soft_instal->id_instalacion          = $instalaciones->id;
    $soft_instal->id_historial            = $historial->id;
    $soft_instal->id_software             = $request->id_software;
    $soft_instal->id_usuario              = $request->id_usuario;
    $soft_instal->id_tipo_venta           = $request->id_tipo_venta;
    $soft_instal->obs_software            = $request->obs_software;
    dd($soft_instal);
    $soft_instal->save();
```

La respuesta del dd es:

[image: Respuesta del DD]

La forma que debería registrar es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes añadir por ejemplo un ``INSERT INTO tabla SELECT columna1,columna2 FROM tutbla;`` si los datos que deseas esta en otra tabla claro...

Comment: no aconsejo hacerlo todo en un solo query, porque necesitas valores intermedios para poder almacenar dicha data, es decir, vas a necesitar conocer que value selecciono del combo y asignarle el key de ese value en especifico para poder retornarlo cuando quieras consultarlo. primero los valores dobles (de listas y combos) obten sus keys, y una vez que en tu tabla registro hayas creado tus foreign key correctamente a cada tabla, simplemente registraras un nuevo elemento con cada uno de los id a los cuales te refieres.